# I need to determine what action to take based on loop control variable

Tags: java, for-loop

Inside of a for loop, I want to determine what action to take based on loop control variable, it get's tricky as you can see from my comments

```
   public void someFunction(int numberOfReps)
   {
     for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReps; i++)
     {
        //if it's first execution; do that, but also do it if it's fourth or eights etc into infinity
        //if it's second execution; do that, but also do it if it's fifth or ninth etc into infinity
        //if it's third execution; do that, but also do it if it's sixth or tenth etc into infinity
     }
   }
```

Comment: Use modulus and the OR operator `||`.

Comment: It sounds like you want to choose an alternative based on the value of `i % 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using modulus operator %4:

0%4 is 0, 4%4 is 0, 8%4 is 0... so it satisfies the first condition

1%4 is 1, 5%4 is 1 ... so it satisfies the second condition
...
..

I am sure you can figure out the rest.

hint: use *continue* keyword to skip executing rest of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

For every condition you need to check, you must have some sort of conditional statement.

You can utilize multiple conditions and the OR operator `||` in Java to determine if one of those conditions have been met. Also worth noting, you can utilize the AND operator `&&` to determine if both conditions have been met.

Eg: say you need to determine if a number equals 1 or is a multiple of 3 (3, 6, 9, 12, etc)

```
if(i == 1 || i % 3 == 0){
    // condition is met
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is something like this?

```
   public void someFunction(int numberOfReps)
   {
     for (int i = 1; i < numberOfReps; i++)
     {
        if(i==1 || i%4==0){
           doFirst();
        //if it's first execution; do that, but also do it if it's fourth or eights etc into infinity
        }else if(i==2 || i%5==0){
           doSecond();
        //if it's second execution; do that, but also do it if it's fifth or ninth etc into infinity
        }else if(i==3 || i%6==0){
           doThird();
        //if it's third execution; do that, but also do it if it's sixth or tenth etc into infinity
        }
      }
    }
```